# Matplotlib matshow with many string labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Today I tried to plot confusion matrix from my classification model.

After search in some pages, I found that `matshow` from `pyplot` can help me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues, labels=None):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cax = ax.matshow(cm)
    plt.title(title)
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    if labels:
        ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
        ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('True')
    plt.show()
```

It works well if I have few labels

```
y_true = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
y_pred = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
labels = list(set(y_true))
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, labels=labels)
```

[image]

But if I have many labels, some labels don't show correctly

```
y_true = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
y_pred = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
labels = list(set(y_true))
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, labels=labels)
```

[image]

My question is how can I display ALL labels in matshow plot? I tried something like `fontdict` but it still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control the frequency of ticks using the [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module.

In this case, you want to set a tick every multiple of `1`, so we can use a [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator)

Add these two lines before you call `plt.show()`:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

And it will produce a tick and label for each letter in your `y_true` and `y_pred`.

I also changed your `matshow` call to make use of the colormap you specify in the function call:

```
cax = ax.matshow(cm,cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

For completeness, your entire function will look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues, labels=None):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # I also added cmap=cmap here, to make use of the 
    # colormap you specify in the function call
    cax = ax.matshow(cm,cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    if labels:
        ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
        ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('True')
    plt.savefig('confusionmatrix.png')
```

Comment: it worked. thank you tom. Another question, do you know how to draw value of confusion matrix in matshow plot?

Comment: its probably better to ask a new question with more details of what you want

Comment: When I put `ax.matshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.7)` after ` ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` it did not work; just a note for others

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) method to specify labels. Your function will look like this (modifying the function from the above answer):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues, labels=None):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # I also added cmap=cmap here, to make use of the 
    # colormap you specify in the function call
    cax = ax.matshow(cm,cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    if labels:
        plt.xticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
        plt.yticks(range(len(labels)), labels)

    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('True')
    plt.savefig('confusionmatrix.png')
```